# Get selected font size/style

Tags: winapi, fonts

What API call is there to get the current front size and style of text? for example, If selected font is `DEFAULT_GUI_FONT` how would you know its size and style (**Bold**, *Italic* etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GetTextMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145132(VS.85).aspx) to get this for selected font

```
typedef struct tagTEXTMETRIC {
  LONG  tmHeight;
  LONG  tmAscent;
  LONG  tmDescent;
  LONG  tmInternalLeading;
  LONG  tmExternalLeading;
  LONG  tmAveCharWidth;
  LONG  tmMaxCharWidth;
  LONG  tmWeight;
  LONG  tmOverhang;
  LONG  tmDigitizedAspectX;
  LONG  tmDigitizedAspectY;
  TCHAR tmFirstChar;
  TCHAR tmLastChar;
  TCHAR tmDefaultChar;
  TCHAR tmBreakChar;
  BYTE  tmItalic;
  BYTE  tmUnderlined;
  BYTE  tmStruckOut;
  BYTE  tmPitchAndFamily;
  BYTE  tmCharSet;
} TEXTMETRIC, *PTEXTMETRIC;
```

Italic is a boolean byte value `tmItalic`.  Boldness is `tmWeight` with values of about 700 or more usually being thought of as "Bold".